# Strange parsing error

Tags: .net

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden<%# Eval("WeekNo") %>" Value="hidden" runat="server" />
```

gives me:

> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Anyone who can tell me why?

Comment: can you post the full html of that tag..

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, down-vote and all, but did I just see Chuck Norris editing this post and then disappear? :)

Comment: See editing history for details.

Comment: Sorry guys, new to the forum and didnt get the formatting right, its fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why would you want to change the ID of your hidden field dynamically instead of passing this information in the value or using a CSS class if you need to access it in javascript. Unfortunately you cannot use dynamic expressions to set the `ID` property of a control.

Comment: Parser Error Message: The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" />

Comment: I am using this in a gridview thats dynamically created at runtime... this hidden value I will use to store the visibilty of the div that surrounds the gridview that is being shown via javascript.

Comment: OK, so, in this case use class selectors for your javascript.

Comment: Class selectors? Could you give me an example?